# start another .cs file in C#.net console

Tags: c#

Im pretty new in C# so i have a question .
I have 2 files in project (Visual Studio).
I have Program.cs file witch is console application what will be ran when executed But then i have included a .cs file because i have a loop and i want it to run a code all the time.
It checks for one procces and if it exists kills it .

```
while (!File.Exists("C://ProgramData//myfile2.jpg"))
{
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCCES NAME");
if (pname.Length == 0) {
Console.Write("The procces doesnt exist!");
}           
else
{
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("procces name "))
{
proc.Kill();
}
}
```

Now i want it to runn all the time but i have other commands i want to be executed at the same time

How do i call/start another .cs file so it will be ran .
im using net 2.0

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll get an answer here. Just read a book on C# basics.

Comment: Sounds like you should search for a tutorial on C# and classes. You don't "run" a .cs file, the complete code base is structured in separate files which work together to form the project.

Comment: Im sorry but i tried to search " run multyble .cs file in c# and got realy weird answers

Comment: That's because it's a really weird question, and I don't think it's what you mean... but it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I Have 2 .cs files in c#.net console application . NOW  When i open the built exe it only runs the 1st .cs file wich is Program.cs But i want it to run the other also because its loop !

Comment: Code files are just a mechanism to organize your code - not to control the flow of it.  Your Program.cs contains the program's entry point (Main()) - you could create additional methods, classes, etc... all in the same file, or you could create additional files to organize your objects.  In either case, the flow of your program is based on how the code is executed.

Comment: If you are wanting to run code concurrently you will need to use the Thread class, which was introduced in .Net 1.1. At least this is what I think you are wanting to do.

Comment: I apologize for saying this but I think you should start with some basics, the method you posted above will just hammer the console and hog the processor since you don't pause or wait between checks, you won't have any processor time left to run any other code, threaded or not.

Comment: i have it . I experienced it and crashed my pc :D . I just added                 Thread.Sleep(1000); and it was okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally each of your .cs files will contain a single class definition containing functionality - such as your little loop to check for a process. If you want to run this functionality you need to find your Program.cs, and create an instance of your class in there, then call your method with your eternal loop in it.

If you want to be able to execute all of your classes at once, not in sequence, you'll need to learn about threading, but essentially you can do:

```
var processThread = new Thread(myClass.CheckForProcess);
processThread.Start();
```

and then if you want to add some extra logic to be run at the same time, you would add that to a separate class in a new .cs file, create another new thread in your Program.cs, and pass in your other eternally-looping-method.

You'll have to add some logic to stop your Program.cs from quitting, but for now you can just make that be a Console.ReadKey until you understand the language better.

*caveat:* This is not a sensible way to write software in the long run, but it is what you're looking for, I believe.